# Windows Server 2003 to 2008 sslstream No Common Algorithm

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, ssl-certificate

I found my issue with the previous question I asked.

It appears as though when connecting between Windows Server 2003 and 2008 using SSLSTREAM in C# the servers are not able to agree on a common algorithm.

The exact SSPI Exception I get is:

```
"The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"
```

I have tried using SSL2, SSL3, TLS1. I tried using Default, I tried installing the AES SSL hotfix for server 2003. It seems no matter what I do, there are no common algorithms..

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Also, when I try the same code on Windows 7 The Server/Client agree on: 
`Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)`

That was taken from wireshark.

Windows Server 2003 does not have that cipher, but it should have some that are compatible without having to enable the ones listed here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766285(WS.10).aspx

Thanks for any help

Comment: I tried changing the group policy item to allow all the ciphers from win2k3 but no luck.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem but maybe it's worth giving a try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030 (How to Restrict the Use of Certain Cryptographic Algorithms and Protocols in Schannel.dll)

Comment: Well, what does wireshark show you for the case that failed? Does the server send a certificate in its server hello?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot figure out from your question which side is the server and which is the client, and maybe it doesn't matter. Although I'm not that familiar with those servers, I have seen similar errors when the server is not able to find its RSA private key, either due to misconfiguration or more often misunderstanding. The server must have access to *both* a private key and its matching public key (contained in its certificate) in order to complete an authenticated connection.

Comment: Client: Win2k3 Server: Wink2k8. The cert I was using is self-signed, and I was not the one who made it. It is password protected though (PK embedded?) I finally seem to have gotten this working by generating a new set of certificates using makecert. Is it possible the certificate I was using prevented certain ciphers from being used?

Comment: ahh, that might be it too. I also vaguely remember that some products may generate DSA certificates and keys instead of RSA. Those could also result in the error message you see. I'd know if I had a look at the wireshark capture file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will try and simulate what happened before and post the results. I noticed that before, I was using a CA Root Certificate.  Also the previous certs were using md5/rsa for the algorithm, hash and thumbprint. When I created new ones I am using Sha1/RSA for them.

Comment: For Posterity: I had a similar problem, and yes, windows (at least server 2003) won't use some ciphers if you generated the certificate with certain settings. The settings that worked for me: **makecert -pe -r -ss my -sr localMachine -n "CN=[DOMAIN NAME OR IP ADDRESS]" -e 01/01/2098 -a sha1 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12** (See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141156 for more info)

Answer (score 0):

The server likely tried to negotiate a SSLv3.0 connection with an AES cipher. That combination is technically illegal. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/08/aes-is-not-a-valid-cipher-for-sslv3.aspx?Redirected=true